# Find infinite loop in progress?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, infinite-loop

Is there a way to find out the current execution of the code to find out the infinite loop?

I have the application running with the current source. I'm attached with the visual studio debugger. I just need to know where the code is currently at so that I can debug it further.

Comment: Hit the pause button. If you need to examine this on a larger, application-wide scale, use a profiler and see where your execution time is going.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're running it from Visual Studio, you can pause the execution with the 'pause' button in the code page. The current line will be in green.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Now I have to wait 12 minutes to accept your answer. :)

Comment: also make sure you have compiled/are running in the debug configuration.  If you compiled for release then you don't get the debugging feature mentioned.

Comment: @gbogumil : That actually depends. Sometime I compile in Release and still get the informations. However, it's not always the case, so yes, Debug is the best alternative.

Comment: In case the problem resides outside of managed code, here is another approach to debugging it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57220007/3195477